# Gridview and RecyclerView synchronized scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

I am trying to build a layout with recyclerview and gridview side by side. I need to sync scroll of both views. Currently, I managed to sync recyclerView with gridView:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                gridView.scrollBy(0, dy);
            }
        });
```

The problem: when gridView is scrolled - cell that are outside of screen do not appear, it's empty.

Second problem: how to sync gridview scrolling with recyclerview?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Can you add some screenshots to indicate how your lists are displayed?

Comment: you can add both views into nested scrollview and enable nestedscrolling so that parent scroll only takes into picture

Comment: @Neha Rathore - That worked, thank you! Appeared to be a very simple solution.